# Unable to run webservice-registry [Eureka server], after converting spring-boot-microservices project from gradle to maven

Tags: maven, spring-boot, gradle, microservices

I am working on spring-boot-microservices project. Reference link is as follows:
https://github.com/rohitghatol/spring-boot-microservices

This project is working properly with gradle.

I have converted this into maven multi module project. After converting this project from gradle to maven, the config server is running , but facing the issue in running the other microservices as they refer the configurations (yml files) from config servers git uri.

When I try to run the webservice-registry - Eureka server , I am getting the following error:

**[nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient : Request execution error
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]**

Can anyone please provide solution in solving this issue.

Thanks and Regards,

Shilpa Kulkarni